# ExtJS 3.3.1 grouptabpanel how to change tab

Tags: extjs, tabs

I have the following tab definition:

```
var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
      layout: 'fit',
      items: {
          xtype: 'grouptabpanel',
          tabWidth: 150,
          id: 'tabPanel',
          activeGroup: undefined,
          items: [aItems1]
      }
  });
```

where `aItems1` is an array of arrays, for example:

```
aItems1[0] = {
    activeTab: 1,
    items: [{
            title: 'foo',
            tabTip: 'foo'
        }, {
            id: 'main-foo1',
            title: 'foo1',
            tabTip: 'foo1',
            iconCls: 'x-icon-page',
            style: 'padding: 10px;',
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [new Inp.Demands()]
        },
        {
            id: 'main-foo2',
            title: 'foo2',
            tabTip: 'foo2',
            iconCls: 'x-icon-exit'
        }
    ]
};
```

And I need to `activate` tab `main-foo2`.

```
var tabPanel = Ext.getCmp('tabPanel');
tabPanel.setActiveTab('main-foo2');
```

But this code did not changed anything.

Using `tabPanel.setActiveTab(NUMBER)`, I can change active group, but what should be done to open exact tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this implementation is basically (but not actually) using two TabPanels.  Thus in order to set the active tab, you'll need to `setActiveGroup` and also `setActiveTab` for the group.

So given the `exactTabId` of the tab you want to open, something like this might work:

```
var tab = Ext.getCmp(exactTabId);
var tabGroup = tab.ownerCt;
var groupingPanel = tabGroup.ownerCt;

groupingPanel.setActiveGroup(tabGroup);
tabGroup.setActiveTab(tab);
```

I was using [GroupTabPanel](http://code.google.com/p/extjsdyntran/source/browse/trunk/extjsdyntran/WebContent/main/ux/GroupTabPanel.js?r=181) and [GroupTab](http://code.google.com/p/extjsdyntran/source/browse/trunk/extjsdyntran/WebContent/main/ux/GroupTab.js?r=181) as a guide to the available methods to call.

Answer (score -3):

```
aItems1[0] = {
            activeGroup:1, //This property is used to activate a specific item
            items: [
                    {
                     title: 'foo',
                     tabTip: 'foo'
                },{
                     id:'main-foo1',
                     title: 'foo1',
                     tabTip: 'foo1',
                     iconCls: 'x-icon-page',
                     style: 'padding: 10px;',
                     layout:'fit',
                     items: [new Inp.Demands()]
                },{
                     id:'main-foo2',
                     title: 'foo2',
                     tabTip: 'foo2',
                     iconCls: 'x-icon-exit'
            }]
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you elaborate more your answer?